# Qt GUI : misaligned things in groupBox with horizontal Layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qlayout, qgroupbox

Very simple :

Ui file : 
[image]

Result :
[image]

"Scans to display" is a groupBox with a horizontal layout which contains two elements :

- Left, a vertical layout with three radio buttons.
- Right, an empty group box.

A red line (added manually on the screenshot) marks the misalignment between those two elements within the "Scans to display" group box.

Of note : the empty groupBox on the right gets automatically filled with numbered checkboxes on startup, the number of which is only known then.

What is going on ? What should I do ?

PS : code to create some number of checkboxes inside the empty groupbox on the right :

```
m_historyButtons[i] = new QCheckBox();
m_historyButtons[i]->setText(QString::number(i));
m_historyButtons[i]->setObjectName(QString("m_pbDisplayEntry%1").arg(i));

QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(true);
m_historyButtons[i]->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);

((QGridLayout*)(ui.m_groupBoxHistoryEntries->layout()))->addWidget(m_historyButtons[i], i/m_grid_width, i%m_grid_width);
```

Comment: you want to get rid of the red line? can you show us the code where you fill the box with the checkboxes?

Comment: In a way, yes, I want to get rid of the red line (which I drew myself on the screenshot). That is to say, if I were to draw it on the screenshot of the result I want, I would find no room to do so, because I want the misalignment to disappear.

Comment: ah ok, now i understand the question. So can you post the relevant code?

Comment: There is none, it's all via ui file - except to create the checkboxes inside the empty group. There all I do is addWidget on the layout of the groupBox with MinimumExpanding for size policy ... see edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt groupboxes leave some room on top, outside the frame, for the groupbox caption. To avoid that, if you don't need a caption, use a QFrame, instead. Newly created checkboxes inside the frame will keep their mutually exclusive beahviour.

Comment: What style to use then to get exactly the looks of a group box without a caption ?

Comment: But that's definitely it though, thanks. I had not thought of that.